# Using the ConnectionKit Framework Within an NSBundle

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbundle

**Update**

I've since spent time learning how to use `install_name_tool` & `otool` to do this properly, and documented the process here: [Using Frameworks Within NSBundles](http://pagesofinterest.net/blog/2012/05/using-frameworks-within-nsbundles/)

---

I would like to use the [Connection Kit](https://github.com/karelia/ConnectionKit) framework within an NSBundle I am making.

To allow my bundle to load the framework successfully, I've changed the `dynamic library install name` to use `@loader_path` as opposed to `@executable_path`.

[image: Connection Kit dynamic library install name]

After building and including the framework in my NSBundle, then building that, running the program that loads my bundle, my bundle fails to load and produces the following output:

```
Error loading MyBundle.rwplugin/Contents/MacOS/MyBundle:  dlopen(/Users/facelap/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyBundle-hiyhdkndcnuhspfqwcuyneqobeou/Build/Products/Debug/MyBundle.rwplugin/Contents/MacOS/MyBundle, 265): Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/DAVKit.framework/Versions/A/DAVKit
  Referenced from: /Users/facelap/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyBundle-hiyhdkndcnuhspfqwcuyneqobeou/Build/Products/Debug/MyBundle.rwplugin/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/Connection.framework/Versions/A/Connection
  Reason: image not found
```

It seems that Connection Kit itself uses a framework.

I also have the source for this framework. I tried setting its `dynamic library install name` to `@loader_path`, but this resulted in similar output (and the bundle failed to loar).

What would a sane entry be for the `dynamic library install name` for a framework within a framework that is to be used within an NSBundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the crash log. It says that you bundle can't load DAVKit.framework so the easiest way - its rebuild ConnectionKit framework but instead of embedding DAVKit.xcodeproj insert all sources of DAVKit. Its easiest way but more correctly - its setup install path of ConnectionKit and DAVKit frameworks. 
Its link should help you:
[embedding frameworks in loadable bundles](http://lapcatsoftware.com/blog/2007/08/11/embedding-frameworks-in-loadable-bundles/)

Comment: Thanks, I might try that. Could you clarify what you mean by 'its setup install path of ConnectionKit and DAVKit...'? I don't understand what you are trying to say there.

Comment: Building DAVKit wihtin ConnectionKit worked, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1):

You should link your bundle with DAVKit and include it there In the same way as you're including ConnectionKit. This avoids having multiple depths of frameworks being shipped

Comment: Ideally, I didn't want to do this for two reasons. #1 was that this would make updating the framework more difficult, i.e. more than just doing a `git pull` on the framework then building & copying it over. #2 simply copying the other frameworks into my project wouldn't work anyway, as I needed to correct the `install path` for the frameworks. I wrote about how to do this here: http://pagesofinterest.net/blog/2012/05/using-frameworks-within-nsbundles/

Comment: Ah, so you don't have ConnectionKit as a submodule then?

Comment: No, but to be honest until I read your comment this didn't occur to me! I have been using it as an external framework. Works well now I learned how to use `install_name_tool` correctly.